# "a letter have/has written by him"

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Which one is correct and why?

> 1. a letter have written by him
> 2. a letter has written by him

And:

> 1. the papers have been corrected by me
> 2. the papers has been corrected by me

Comment: James, please go and look up the verb have. Also, look up what happens in the third person to verbs in English. I do not know what your native language is but these are "baby" questions.

Answer (score 2):

Well in the first instance, neither.

"a letter has been written by him" or "a letter was written by him" would be correct.

Singular=has, plural=have.
Past tense singular="has been," or "was."
Past tense plural="have been," or "were."

I suspect you will see the answer to the second instance with this knowledge :)

Comment: "Has been" and "have been" might be better dubbed "present perfect".  (Re-posting the comment because there was a typo in the original.)

Answer (score 1):

@James,

I follow up after the contributions from @CaptainSkyfish and @rjpond.

Present perfect = (singular) "has been" and (plural) "have been"

'the papers have been corrected by me' is correct.

The other one is ungrammatical.